# String array with Core Dump (using templates and operator overloading)

Tags: c++, arrays, string, operator-overloading, coredump

I am trying to understand something about string arrays and core dumps. So, I created a class template with a few operator overloaded functions that add and remove elements. When I tested the addition and subtraction overloaded methods on int, double, and char specializations, the program added and removed the elements perfectly (no core dump); however, when trying this on strings I get a core dump. I made sure to have `#include <string>` and using std::string. Can anyone explain why this works on int, double, and char specializations, but not on strings?

```
template <class T> T Set<T>::iVal;
template <class T> T Set<T>::DELIM;

template <class T>

//
//default constructor
//
Set<T>::Set ( int s ){

        psize = ( s > 0 ? s: DEFAULTSIZE);
        //allocate an array of specified size
        set = new T[ psize ];

        if(!set) {
                //send an error is system cannot allocate memory
                cout << "Cannot Allocate Memory, exiting program... " << endl;
                exit (1);
        }

        for ( int i = 0; i < psize; i++){
                set[i] = iVal;
        }

        numOfElements = 0;
}

//
//custom constructor
//
template <class T>
Set<T>::Set( T array[] , int size, char name ){

        set = new T[size];

        psize = ( size > 0 ? size: DEFAULTSIZE);
        numOfElements = size;
        for ( int i = 0; i < psize; i++){
                set[i] = array[i];
        }

        if (!set){
                cout << "Cannot Allocate Memory, exiting program... " << endl;
                exit(1);
        }

        Set::name = name;
}

//
//subtraction operator that removes elements
//
template <class T>
bool Set<T>::operator-( T n ){
        bool status = false;
                for ( int i = 0; i < numOfElements; i++){
                        if ( set [i] == n ){
                                for ( int j = i; j < numOfElements; j++){
                                        set [j] = set[j + 1];
                                }

                                set[numOfElements - 1] = n;
                                --numOfElements;
                        }

                        status = true;
                }

                return (status);
}
//
//addition operator that adds elements
//
template <class T>
bool Set<T>::operator+( T n ){
        bool status = false;

        if ( !element(n) ){
                if ( psize == numOfElements ) {
                        T *ptr = new T[psize += 1];

                        for ( int i = 0; i < numOfElements; i++ )
                                ptr[i] = set[i];

                        delete [] set;

                        set = ptr;

                        psize += 1;

                        delete [] ptr;

                }

                set[numOfElements] = n;
                numOfElements += 1;

                status = true;
        }

        return status;

}
//In Driver
 //
        //Creating string arrays using the custom constructor to instantiate objects
        //
        string s1[4] = { "turtle" , "fish", "shark" , "lobster" };
        string s2[3] = { "turtle", "book", "pencil" };

        //
        //Testing string specialization
        //
        cout << "\nTesting strings.\n" << endl;
        Set <string> string1 ( s1, 4, 'A' );
        Set <string> string2 ( s2, 3, 'B' );
        //setting delimiter
        Set <string>::setDELIM ("stop");
        //
        //testing the addition and subtraction of elements
        //CORE DUMP HAPPENS HERE
        string1 - "shark";
        cout << "\nAfter removing an element from Set A, Set A = " << string1 << endl;
        string1 + "dolphin";
        cout << "\nAfter adding an element to Set A, Set A = " << string1 << endl;
```

Comment: To avoid ambiguity: psize is physical size, numOfElements is acting as a fillsize (what my instructor wanted us to call it) and the function called element is a boolean function that returns true if set [i] is equal to a particular value that is being passed and returns false otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a couple of problems that are both undefined behaviour.  The fact that it works with other datatypes may just be due to luck.

First, let's look at your `-` method:

```
if ( set [i] == n ){
    for ( int j = i; j < numOfElements; j++){
        set [j] = set[j + 1];  // <-- Access past last element in array
    }

    set[numOfElements - 1] = n;
    --numOfElements;
}
```

That inner loop above should test `j < numOfElements - 1`.  That way, `set[j+1]` will not look at the element past the end of the array (if `numOfElements` happens to be the same as the allocated size).

Now let's look at your `+` method:

```
T *ptr = new T[psize += 1];
for ( int i = 0; i < numOfElements; i++ )
        ptr[i] = set[i];
delete [] set;
set = ptr;
psize += 1;
delete [] ptr;  // <-- BOOM!
```

In the above, you just deleted `set`, then replaced it with new memory pointed to by `ptr`.  But then you deleted that memory.  If you remove the marked line, this should work.